# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '%ProgramData%\\Microsoft\\app.exe' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-not-found, python-os

I am trying to start a process using `os.startfile` . But when I run it, I get the following error!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-3c26e36152b3> in <module>
      1 import os
----> 2 os.startfile(r"%ProgramData%\Microsoft\DeviceSync\app.exe")

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '%ProgramData%\\Microsoft\\DeviceSync\\app.exe'
```

But if I use the full path

```
import os
os.startfile(r"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\DeviceSync\app.exe")
```

It runs fine.
What am I doing wrong?  :(

Comment: it may sends path directly to system but `%ProgramData%` can be variable replaced by shell (command line). You may try to get `%ProgramData%` from `os.environ` and replace in your string, or you can try `os.path.expandvars(r"%ProgramData%\Microsoft\app.exe")`

Comment: @furas Thank u for your comment. And I tried.                                                      ```import os 
x=os.path.expandvars(r"%ProgramData%\Microsoft\DeviceSync\app.exe")   
os.startfile(x)``` It starts the file, but the file isn't working. It's not giving any output. But if I manually double-click it, it works.

Comment: maybe you should use `subprocess.run(x)` to get output.

Comment: @furas I tried everything `subprocess.run ` , `subprocess.call` , `subprocess.popen` but it's the same runs the process but doesn't give any output i.e (store data in a text file)

Comment: did you check what path you get with `os.path.expandvars()`? Maybe it runs file in different folder. In question you show path with `\Microsoft\app.exe` but in comment `\Microsoft\DeviceSync\app.exe` - you use two different paths. If code works with `os.startfile(r"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\app.exe")` then why to use `%ProgramData%` - I think all Windows have the same `%ProgramData%` and there is no need to use it.

Comment: @furas the real path is `"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\DeviceSync\app.exe"` and this is the path I get with `os.path.expandvars()`. Yeah! Almost all pcs have the same “program data” but some people want to feel smart, and they change the drive letters. That's y I have to use program data, so that no matter what the drive letter is it could find the “program data”  folder.

Comment: but you use `os.startfile(r"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\app.exe")` without `DeviceSync` - so if it is typo then correct it in question. And if it is NOT typo then you use wrong path in version with `%ProgramData%`. I don't use Windows so I can't test it - and I can't help more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows
***`So looking at your problem what you can do is actuall create a short of the file you want to start`***
For example, create a shortcut like. Right-click your EXE file and from the drop-down menu select the Create Shortcut option.

```
App.exe
App.exe.lnk
```

Then should Try

```
import os      
x=os.path.expandvars(r"%ProgramData%\Microsoft\DeviceSync\app.exe.lnk")                          
os.startfile(x)
```

It should Work Normally and give you the output

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed. It worked Perfectly.              Sorry, I can't upvote your answer.